# How can I parse long strings from an online xml file in Android application?

Tags: java, android, parsing

I want to parse a very long string from an xml file. You can see the xml file [here](http://www.aboutsports.co.uk/fixtures/).
 If you visit the above file, there is a `"description" tag` from which I want to parse the string. When there is a short short string, say 3-lines or 4-lines string in the `"description" tag`, then my parser(Java SAX parser) easily parse the string but, when the string is hundreds of lines then my parser cannot parse the string. You can check my code that I am using for the parsing and please let me know where I am going wrong in this regard. Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you for this act of kindness.

Here is the parser GetterSetter class

```
public class MyGetterSetter 
{
    private ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();


        public ArrayList<String> getDescription()
        { 
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) 
        { 


            this.description.add(description);
        }
}
```

Here is the parser Handler class

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler 
{
    String elementValue = null;
    Boolean elementOn = false;
    Boolean item = false;

    public static MyGetterSetter data = null;

    public static MyGetterSetter getXMLData() 
    {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setXMLData(MyGetterSetter data) 
    {
        MyHandler.data = data;
    }


    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        data =  new MyGetterSetter();
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {

    }

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
    {
        elementOn = true;

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
        item = true;
    }

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        elementOn = false;

        if(item)
        {

            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
                {   
                data.setDescription(elementValue);


                Log.d("--------DESCRIPTION------", elementValue +" ");

                }


            else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) item = false;
        }



    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
        if (elementOn) 
        {
            elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            elementOn = false;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you want the content of every `description` tag?

Comment: Yes dear I want the content of every description tag.

Comment: "... cannot parse the string..." What does that mean? You get an exception? A null string? An empty string?

Comment: I receive an empty string.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). it would make something like this much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the org.w3c.dom package.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.aboutsports.co.uk/fixtures/");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(url.openStream());

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("item"); // get <item> nodes

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = list.item(i);
            NodeList descriptions = ((Element)item).getElementsByTagName("description"); // get <description> nodes within an <item>
            for (int j = 0; j < descriptions.getLength(); j++) {
                Node description = descriptions.item(0);

                System.out.println(description.getTextContent()); // print the text content
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) in java is also great for extracting bits from XML documents. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java) an example.

You would use a `XPathExpression` like `/item/description`. When you would evaluate it on the XML `InputStream`, it would return a `NodeList` like above with all the `<description>` elements within a `<item>` element.

If you wanted to do it your way, with a `DefaultHandler`, you would need to set and unset flags so you can check if you are in the body of a `<document>` element. The code above probably does something similar internally, hiding it from you. The code is available in java, so why not use it?